# Split nested list in the columns in a dataframe

Tags: r

Below is a data frame in R, where the second column is a character vector:

```
COlA     COlB
  1      list(ved = "19", ved_name = "No", vedd = "11")
  2      list(ved = c("65", "83", "2"), ved_name = c("At", "Re", "Rum"), vedd = c("11", "11", "11"))
```

How can I transform this data into the expected output below?

Expected Output

```
COlA       COlB-ved         COlB-ved_name              COlB-vedd
1               19                   No                       11
2               65                   At                       11
2               83                   Re                       11
2                2                  Rum                       11
```

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(COlA = c(1, 2), 
                     COlB = c("list(ved = \"19\", ved_name = \"No\", vedd = \"11\")",  
"list(ved = c(\"65\", \"83\", \"2\"), ved_name = c(\"At\", \"Re\", \"Rum\"), vedd = c(\"11\", \"11\", \"11\"))" )), 
                row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to `parse` and `eval` the R expressions in character format, then `unnest` them:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df$COlB <- lapply(df$COlB, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))

df %>% unnest_auto(COlB) %>% unnest(cols = c(ved, ved_name, vedd))
#> Using `unnest_wider(COlB)`; elements have 3 names in common
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>    COlA ved   ved_name vedd 
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <chr>
#> 1     1 19    No       11   
#> 2     2 65    At       11   
#> 3     2 83    Re       11   
#> 4     2 2     Rum      11
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Great thanks. But actually her ColB is not a nested list. It is the character . Here is the ````structure(list(COlA = c(1, 2), COlB = c("list(ved = \"19\", ved_name = \"No\", vedd = \"11\")", 
"list(ved = c(\"65\", \"83\", \"2\"), ved_name = c(\"At\", \"Re\", \"Rum\"), vedd = c(\"11\", \"11\", \"11\"))"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))````

Comment: @Vinod thanks. Please see my update. It's always better to include your `dput` in the question, since it was unclear what format the data was in, and this led to your question being closed. I have voted to reopen it.

Comment: If this has solved your problem please consider marking the answer as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  c(
    make.row.names = FALSE,
    lapply(split(df, seq(nrow(df))), function(v) cbind(v[1], eval(str2expression(v$COlB))))
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  COlA ved ved_name vedd
1    1  19       No   11
2    2  65       At   11
3    2  83       Re   11
4    2   2      Rum   11
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution for completeness:

```
setDT(df)
df[, eval(str2expression(COlB)), by = COlA]
#    COlA ved ved_name vedd
# 1:    1  19       No   11
# 2:    2  65       At   11
# 3:    2  83       Re   11
# 4:    2   2      Rum   11
```